# Why don't my font-awesome video icons work when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The following code uses font-awesome icons for video controls (E.G. play, stop, pause, etc...), however, when I run the following code, it doesn't work as expected.

```js
var lecteur = document.getElementById("mavideo");

function lecture() {
  lecteur.play();
}
function pause() {
  lecteur.pause();
}
function stop() {
  lecteur.pause();
  lecteur.currentTime = 0;
}
function avancer() {
  lecteur.currentTime += 10;
}
function reculer() {
  lecteur.currentTime -= 10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p>Here is our dresses in 2019</p>
<form>
  <video src="dresses fashion.mp4" width="1000" id="mavideo" > </video> 
  <br />
  <button onclick="lecture()"><i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button onclick="pause()"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button  onclick="stop()"><i class="fas fa-stop" style="font-size:36px;"> </i> </button>
  <button onclick="reculer()"><i class="fas fa-caret-left" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button onclick="avancer()"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size:36px;"></i></button>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the above js code is in the video.js file

Comment: what doesn't work? controls? font-awesome? not really sure what you need

Comment: Check for the javascript file address, there might be a chance you haven't put the correct address of it.

Comment: I know this is completely off topic, but the correct spelling for `lectuer` is `lecture`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, put your HTML `style="..."` attributes in a CSS file or put them in between `style` tags.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" />
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  /* NOTE: instead of using "<br />" use "margin-bottom" instead */
  video {width: 1000px; margin-bottom: 20px}
  i.fas {font-size: 36px}
</style>
```

**NOTE:** The `link` and `style` elements should go in the `head` element and the `integrity` & `crossorigin` attributes aren't necessary so I've removed them.

Second, your `video` tags aren't supposed to go in forms, move your video tag and it's accompanying `button` tags to another (semantic) container, for example a `section`, like this:

```
<p>Here is our dresses in 2019</p>
<section class="video-container">
  <video src="dresses fashion.mp4" id="mavideo"></video> 
  <button><i class="fas fa-play"></i></button>
  <button><i class="fas fa-pause"></i></button>
  <button><i class="fas fa-stop"></i></button>
  <button><i class="fas fa-caret-left"></i></button>
  <button><i class="fas fa-caret-right"></i></button>
</section>
```

The source: `dresses fashion.mp4` should be `dresses_fashion.mp4`, i.e. using an underscore instead of a space, this makes it easier to identify that this is actually a file and not a file in a directory, like `dresses/fashion.mp4`.

Third, try changing your `video` tag to look like this:

```
<video controls="true">
  <source src="path/to/video_name.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="path/to/video_name.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <p class="fallback">Your browser does not support HTML5 videos.</p>
</video>
```

Finally, move your JavaScript events from HTML to JavaScript.

```
// select the video element
var lecture = document.querySelector("#mavideo");

// play the video
document.querySelector(".fa-play").addEventListener("click", function() {
  lecture.play();
});

// pause the video
document.querySelector(".fa-pause").addEventListener("click", function() {
  lecture.pause();
});

// stop the video
document.querySelector(".fa-stop").addEventListener("click", function() {
  lecture.pause();
  lecture.currentTime=0;
});

// skip backwards by 10 seconds
document.querySelector(".fa-caret-left").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(lecture.currentTime < (lecture.duration - 11)) {
    lecture.currentTime += 10;
  }
});

// skip forwards by 10 seconds
document.querySelector(".fa-caret-right").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if(lecture.currentTime > 10) {
    lecture.currentTime -= 10;
  }
});
```

**NOTE:** you could also use `document.getElementsByClassName("...")[0]` instead of `document.querySelector`.

**NOTE:** instead of calling the `addEventListener` method, you could set the `onclick` property to your handler function.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p> Here is our dresses in 2019</p>
<form>
  <video src="dresses fashion.mp4" width="1000" type="video/mp4" id="mavideo" > </video> 
  <br>
  <button onclick="lecture()"><i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button onclick="pause()"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button  onclick="stop()"><i class="fas fa-stop" style="font-size:36px;"> </i> </button>
  <button onclick="reculer()"><i class="fas fa-caret-left" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button onclick="avancer()"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size:36px;"></i></button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
var lecteur = document.getElementById("mavideo");

function lecture(){
  lecteur.play();
}

function pause(){
    lecteur.pause();
}

function stop(){
  lecteur.pause();
  lecteur.currentTime=0;
}

function avancer(){
  lecteur.currentTime+=10;
}

function reculer(){
  lecteur.currentTime-=10;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Inline javascript is never a good approach, there is some event firing when you click those buttons because your video is in a form, I don't know why, it shouldn't be in a form, so you should add `event.preventDefault()` for listening to click events. I've added a sample video for you to check the methods. Use id's for click events, and perform the functions accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById("play").onclick = function(event) { // click event
  event.preventDefault() // prevent anything else
  document.getElementById("mavideo").play() // play the video by it's id
}

document.getElementById("pause").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("mavideo").pause()
}
document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("mavideo").pause()
  document.getElementById("mavideo").currentTime=0;
}
document.getElementById("avancer").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("mavideo").currentTime+=10;
}

document.getElementById("reculer").onclick = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  document.getElementById("mavideo").currentTime-=10;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p> Here is our dresses in 2019</p>
<form>
  <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" width="1000" id="mavideo" > </video> 
  <br>
  <button id="play"><i class="fas fa-play" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button id="pause"><i class="fas fa-pause" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button id="stop"><i class="fas fa-stop" style="font-size:36px;"> </i> </button>
  <button id="reculer"><i class="fas fa-caret-left" style="font-size:36px;"></i> </button>
  <button id="avancer"><i class="fas fa-caret-right" style="font-size:36px;"></i></button>
</form>
```